# Why do we have $\psi^{(m)} (z)=(-1)^{m+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^me^{-zt}}{1-e^{-t}}dt$?

Tags: derivatives, special-functions, gamma-function

Why is the following representation true?
$$\psi^{(m)} (z)=(-1)^{m+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t^me^{-zt}}{1-e^{-t}}dt,$$

where $\psi^{(m)} (z)$ denotes the [Polygamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function).

Comment: The above formula is valid for $m \ge 1$. I can be easily derived from [the integral representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) of digamma function by the differentiation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question really is: why do we have
$$\psi^{(1)}(z)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{te^{-zt}dt}{1-e^{-t}},\tag{1}$$
since the statement for $m>1$ is obtained by straightforward differentiation with respect to $z$. (Also note that we cannot set $m=0$ since the integral will become divergent.)

The formula (1) is an easy consequence of the infinite product representation for the gamma function (see formula (16) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html)):
$$\Gamma(z)=\left[ze^{\gamma z}\prod_{k=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)e^{-z/k}\right]^{-1}.$$
Taking the logarithm at both sides of this relation and differentiating twice w.r.t. $z$, we find
$$\psi^{(1)}(z)=\frac{d^2}{dz^2}\ln\Gamma(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z+k)^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z+k)^2}.\tag{2}$$
To show that (1) and (2) are equivalent, it suffices to expand $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-e^{-t}}$ in (1) into geometric series and observe that
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}te^{-(z+k)t}dt=\frac{1}{(z+k)^2}.$$

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh For $\psi^{(0)}(z)$ the formula you have written is not true - its right hand side is divergent. The analog of that formula for $m=0$ is the formula (17) [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html).

Comment: for $\psi^{(0)} (z)$ I took the integral of $$\int_{0}^{\infty}te^{-(z+k)t}dt=\frac{1}{(z+k)^2}.$$ with respect to z but I faild to show the formula like in (17)

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh No, if you naively expand the integrand into geometric series for $m=0$, you will have $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(z+k) t}dt=\frac{1}{z+k}$. And the sum $\sum_k\frac{1}{z+k}$ is divergent, as was divergent (at $t=0$) the initial integral.

Comment: that is what i did : $$\psi^{(1)} (z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(z+k)^2}$$
$$\psi^{(0)} (z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{-1}{(z+k)}$$
$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{(z+k)t}dt=\frac{-1}{(z+k)}$$
$$\psi ^{(0)}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{-e^{(zt)}}{e^t-1}dt$$

where is the wrong ?

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh First wrong thing is the passage from the 1st line to the 2nd (one cannot integrate term by term without checking convergence).  Another wrong thing is the right side of the 4th line: when $t$ (note that denominator should be $e^t-1$ instead of $e^z-1$) is small, the integrand is approximately equal to $-1/t$, its antiderivative behaves as $-\ln t$ and this diverges on the lower bound.

Comment: sorry but to now I dont know how to get $\psi^{(0)}(z)$ ???

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh In which form do you want to have it? The integral form is the formula (17) I've mentioned above. In the form of a sum it is obtained in the same way as (2) of my answer, but you differentiate once instead of twice. The point is that the sum which arises is of the form $\sum\left(\frac{1}{z+k}-\frac{1}{k}\right)$ and this does converge.

Comment: tkanks alot but now the question is what is the $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{z+k})$ ?? 
if I know the answer of the sum it take me to know the $\psi^{(0)} (z)$

Comment: @hmedan.mnsh I don't understand your question. This sum **is** $\psi(z)$. What do you mean by "the answer of the sum"? Btw I think this discussion is already way too long for comments. If you have a specific question, please ask it on the main board - the people (including myself) will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Start by the following

$$\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{e^{-(x+1)t}}{1-e^{-t}}\, dt$$

Making the substitution $e^{-t}=y$

$$\int^{1}_0 \frac{1}{-\log(y)}-\frac{y^{t}}{1-y}\, dy$$

By a little trick we have

$$\int^{1}_0 \frac{1}{-\log(y)}-\frac{1}{1-y}\, dy +\int^1_0 \frac{1-y^{t}}{1-y}\, dy$$

The left hand is another form of the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

$$-\gamma +\int^1_0 \frac{1-y^{t}}{1-y}\, dy=\psi(t+1)$$

Hence we have

$$\psi(x+1)=\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{e^{-(x+1)t}}{1-e^{-t}}\, dt$$

or

$$\psi(x)=\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{e^{-t}}{t}-\frac{e^{-xt}}{1-e^{-t}}\, dt$$

The first derivative shows

$$\psi'(x)=\int^{\infty}_0 \frac{te^{-xt}}{1-e^{-t}}\, dt$$

And the result follows by continuous differentiation with respect to $x$.

Look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant#Integrals

Comment: Do you know how to prove that 

$$\psi(x+1)=-\gamma +\int^1_0 \frac{1-t^x}{1-t}\, dt$$

Comment: yes I know but how you started with prove because I started with $\psi(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}(\ln n -\sum_{m=0}^{n}(\frac{1}{z+m}))$

Comment: You made it difficult to start withm because it is easier to start with an integral representation and prove the equivalent series representation .